# My voice is naturally nasal! Is there any app to change my recorded voice?

Tags: voice-recording, audio-editing

Naturally, it seems like I speak from my nose instead of the mouth. When I record my voice for online courses, it's even worse. I really hate my recorded voice.

The converted voice should not be very different from my **natural** voice! I just want to clean it: Not nasal! That is, I would like to change my voice a little.

I prefer an app working in Linux as it's my default operating system.

Comment: What kind of noise is it? There are hundreds of different noises. Can you provide a sample sound file?

Comment: In my case, using a better microphone helped much more than post processing by Software.

Comment: A better microphone does not make change in my voice. I want to change it a little!

Answer (score 1):

If it is noise like the studio definition of noise (white noise etc.), you can try [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/download/linux).

There is e.g. `Effect / Noise removal` which can help to reduce noise or `Effect / Click removal`.

Comment: Nope, It's not environmental noise! My natural voice is nasal!

Answer (score 1):

There is software to do this, but it's pretty expensive.

If you're starting off you could get software like [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) to do some basic audio (voice) manipulation because it's free.

Or if you have some cash to spend you could buy a program [from this website](http://www.antarestech.com/products/index.php).
The price range is from 70 USD to 700 USD.